# Two definitions of Hilbert cube

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

The Hilbert cube is defined as $H=[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$. This is metrizable space with the metric defined by $d(x,y)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}|x_i-y_i|$, where $x=(x_i)$ and $y=(y_i)$. It is also defined as the metric subspace of $\ell^2$ space as
$H'=\{(x_i)\mid 0\leq x_i \leq \frac{1}{i}\}$. I know both are homeomorphic topological spaces. I want to prove it in the capacity of metric spaces. The obvious map $f:H\to H'$ is $f((x_i))=(\frac{x_i}{i})$. How can I show that $f$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0.$ Fix $N\in\Bbb N$ large enough, so that
$$\sum_{k>N}\frac1{k^2}\le\frac\varepsilon2,$$
and define then $\delta>0$ by:
$$\sum_{k=1}^N\left(\frac{2^k}k\right)^2\delta^2=\frac\varepsilon2.$$
For every $x,y\in H$ such that $d(x,y)\le\delta,$ we have:
$$\sum_{k\ge1}\left(\frac{x_k-y_k}k\right)^2\le\sum_{k=1}^N\left(\frac{2^k\delta}k\right)^2+\sum_{k>N}\left(\frac1k\right)^2\le\varepsilon.$$